# Converting Linq MemberExpression lambda to work on class with reference

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

For this question, I'll use the standard structure of Products (with an IsActive flag) and OrderItems (that each reference a Product).  I also have a query builder that generates Linq expressions used to query products.  A sample filter would let the user find active/inactive products, generating a Linq expression like:

```
Expression<Func<Product, bool>> testProductActive = product => !product.IsActive;
```

I want to take that expression and use it to test an `IQueryable<OrderItem>`.  I can do it with in-memory collections using `Expression.Invoke`:

```
public static Expression<Func<TDestination, TResult>> Translate<TSource, TDestination, TResult>(this Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>> @this, Expression<Func<TDestination, TSource>> getSourceFromDestination)
{
    ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TDestination), "arg");

    Expression invokedGetSource = Expression.Invoke(getSourceFromDestination, param);
    Expression invokedOriginalBody = Expression.Invoke(@this, invokedGetSource);

    Expression<Func<TDestination, TResult>> result = Expression.Lambda<Func<TDestination, TResult>>(invokedOriginalBody, param);
    return result;
}
```

Which I would call like:

```
Expression<Func<OrderItem, bool>> testOrderItemProductActive = testProductActive.Translate<Product, OrderItem, bool>(orderItem => orderItem.Product);
```

But NHibernate.Linq (and from what I've seen in questions, Linq to Entities) does not support `Expression.Invoke`.

Is there a way to take the MemberExpression from `testProductActive` and turn it into `!orderItem.Product.IsActive`?

---

Note: In a real-life example, I would have a collection of `Expression<Func<Product, bool>>` expressions generated by visible filters that would all need converted.  Right now I've got my filters generating expressions for both types of records, but I'd love to drop the duplication and make it so an existing filter could be used for a different type of record without changing the filter's own code.

Comment: There was an old question which showed a visitor for combining Expresson.Invoke - looking for it...

Comment: Found it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717444 - that will let you use `Expression.Invoke` but flatten it back to a single (`Invoke`-free) `Expression`. Not sure if this is then a dupe?

Comment: @Mark, upvoting your linked answer just because it looks cool!

Comment: While the other question asks a bit different question, your Invoke inline does the trick quite nicely. Closing for duplicate. Thanks, Marc.

Answer (score 0):

It's not in quite the same vein as what you're proposing, but check out **[Dynamic Linq.](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)**