# "The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities" - stumped!

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

In my EF later, I'm trying to pass in an anonymous function to be used as part of my Linq query. The function would pass in an INT and return a BOOL (u.RelationTypeId is an INT). Below is a simplified version of my function:

```
public IEnumerable<UserBandRelation> GetBandRelationsByUser(Func<int, bool> relation)
{
    using (var ctx = new OpenGroovesEntities())
    {
        Expression<Func<UsersBand, bool>> predicate = (u) => relation(u.RelationTypeId);

        var relations = ctx.UsersBands.Where(predicate);

        // mapping, other stuff, back to business layer
        return relations.ToList();
    }
}
```

However, I get the error stated above. It seems like I'm going everything correct by building a predicate from the function. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You're trying to pass an arbitrary .NET function in... how could the entity framework hope to translate that into SQL? You can change it to take an `Expression<Func<int, bool>>` instead, and build the `Where` clause from that, although it won't be *particularly* easy, because you'll need to rewrite the expression with a different parameter expression (i.e. replacing whatever parameter expression is in the original expression tree with the expression of calling `u.RelationTypeId`).

To be honest, for the sake of just specifying `u.RelationTypeId` in the lambda expression that you use to create the expression tree to pass into the method, you'd be better off just using:

```
public IEnumerable<UserBandRelation> GetBandRelationsByUser(
    Expression<Func<UsersBand, bool>> predicate)
{
    using (var ctx = new OpenGroovesEntities())
    {
        var relations = ctx.UsersBands.Where(predicate);

        // mapping, other stuff, back to business layer
        return relations.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's sort of what I thought, but my problem is that UserBandRelation is a model while UsersBand is my entity model. I use automapper to map these. Automapper has a problem if I try something crazy like mapping the expressions. Is there any way around this, in order to keep my entities separate? Thanks.

Comment: @Ryan: As I say, you could try to go about doing expression tree rewriting. It's just not something I've tried... I also haven't used Automapper, so I'm not quite sure where that comes into it.

Comment: @Ryan somewhere here on SO is a sample I wrote that will happen flatten `Expression.Invoke` for the purpose of allowing EF to work with sub-expressions (something L2S supports out-of-the-box). It still can't work with delegates, of course - In just saying that a rewriter is here somewhere...

Comment: @Ryan [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717444/combining-two-lamba-expressions-in-c/1720642#1720642), in fact - just enable "inline"

Comment: @Ryan @Marc There is also [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx), which incorporates many features needed for manipulating expressions.

Comment: I second Chris's suggestion of LinqKit => it makes chaining Expression<Func<YourType, bool>> predicates together extremely easy.

Comment: @JonSkeet: That's great, but I have a similar case where the property                  I need to evaluate is determined at run time by the user. So I tried `Expression<Func<Hotel, decimal>> getProperty = h => h.NumberOfDiamonds;` and then `query = query.Where(h => getProperty(h) == 0)` but I get the error `getProperty is a variable but is used like a method`. Is that possible?

Answer (score 127):

I was getting this very error and I'm using Entity Framework with [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) by Joe Albahari to build dynamic `where` clauses. If you happen to be in the same condition, you should call the `AsExpandable` method:

If querying with *Entity Framework*, change the last line to this:

> `return objectContext.Products.AsExpandable().Where(predicate);`

This method is part of LINQKIT DLL that you can grab [here](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) or through a NuGet package [here](http://nuget.org/packages/LinqKit).

Everything works fine now. :)

Comment: Do you know if `AsExpandable()` causes any performance impact? I am using a generic repository and only use the predicate builder occasionally, is it worth it to create a separate repository method for predicate building?

Comment: @Cody... I have no idea. You'd better ask that to Joe Albahary directly. :) This is his twitter: https://twitter.com/linqpad

Comment: @DoctorOreo Have you figured out the performance impact? I'm in the same situation as you

Comment: @Marc you know what, I've been using it since I guess April of 2014 and I haven't noticed any issues. Going on a year and a half now in a production application, nobody has complained. (this is a system with ~50 users dealing with anywhere from 10,000 to 5,000,000 records)

Comment: Looks like with the latest version you don't need to use `AsExpandable()` to pass in the predicate to `Where()`. Possibly because of the new `PredicateBuilder.New<T>()` starting point?

Answer (score 5):

You can call the `Expand()` method on your `predicate` before the `Where` request.

Comment: This works too ! And I don't know what AsExpandable do, so I prefer to just call Expand when I really want to filter the query.

Answer (score -7):

I know this answer is really late, but I ran into the same problem and it led me here, so I thought I'd share my solution.

I read Leniel's answer, and it gave me an idea. The default types have the method "AsEnumerable()" which behaves the same way, alleviating the issue.

Comment: `AsEnumerable()` will cause the `Where()` function to be invoked by Linq to Objects and not Linq to Entities.