# Building an expression tree for EF with invoke

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, expression-trees

Jon Skeet has a good answer ([LINQ Between Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447635/linq-between-operator)) about how to write an expression tree which will run in LINQ to SQL to perform a between operation. Ive tried this with EF but it fails due to the Invoke call below being unsupported.

```
    public static Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> Between<TSource, TKey>(Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector, TKey low, TKey high) where TKey : IComparable<TKey>
    {
        Expression key = Expression.Invoke(keySelector, keySelector.Parameters.ToArray());
```

> The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to
>   Entities.

Is there an alternative to Invoke which can be used here to get the property specified by the input lambda so this works with EF?

Comment: check whether this helps..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284912/the-linq-expression-node-type-invoke-is-not-supported-in-linq-to-entities

Comment: @Saravanan I think its a different issue, he is dealing specifically with a passed in lambda which isn't expressionised, this question relates specifically to building an expression tree.

Comment: Have a look at [LINQKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx), it can rewrite the expression to remove the `Invoke()`, so that EF can understand it.