# Query and map complex objects

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-entities, expression-trees

My goal is to query and map complex objects with as little overhead as possible. I am working with a large database with lots of related tables. I am trying to use LINQ select and projection to select only the necessary information i need to make the object.

This is the original query I had which was fast and worked great.

```
List<ClientDTO> clientList = dbClients.Select(client =>
new ClientDTO
{
    ID = client.ClientID,
    FirstName = client.FirstName,
    LastName = client.LastName,
    //etc....
    Products = client.Products
        .Select(prod => new ProductDTO
        {
            ID = prod.ID,
            DateOfTransaction = prod.Date,
            //etc...
        }).ToList(),
    Items = client.Items
        .Select(item => new ItemDTO
        {
            ID = item.ID,
            Date = item.Date,
            //etc...
        }
});
```

Keep in mind the Client table has over 50 related tables, so this query worked great in that it only selected the fields I needed to make the object.

Now what I needed to do is make mappers for these Objects and try to build the same query statement but using the mappers this time. Here is what I ended up with.

```
List<ClientDTO> clients = dbClients.ProjectToClientDTO();
```

Using these Mappers

```
public static List<ClientDTO> ProjectToClientDTO(this IQueryable<Clients> query)
{
    var clientList = query.Select(client => new
    {
        ID = client.ClientID,
        FirstName = client.FirstName,
        LastName = client.LastName,
        //etc...
        Products = client.Products.AsQueryable().ProjectToProductDTO().ToList(),
        Items = client.Items.AsQueryable().ProjectToItemDTO().ToList()
    }

    List<ClientDTO> dtoClientList = new List<ClientDTO>();
    foreach (var client in clientList)
    {
        ClientDTO clientDTO = new ClientDTO();

        clientDTO.EncryptedID = EncryptID(client.ID, client.FirstName, client.LastName);
        //etc...
        clientDTO.Products = client.Products;
        clientDTO.Items = client.Items;
    }
    return dtoClientList;
}

public static IQueryable<ProductDTO> ProjectToProductDTO(this IQueryable<Products> query)
{
    return query.Select(prod => new ProductDTO
    {
        ID = prod.ID,
        DateOfTransaction = prod.Date,
        //etc...
    });
}

public static IQueryable<ItemDTO> ProjectToItemDTO(this IQueryable<Items> query)
{
    return query.Select(item => new ItemDTO
    {
        ID = item.ID,
        Date = item.Date,
        //etc...
    });
}
```

After trying to run this I get the following error.

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'ProjectToProductDTO(IQueryable[Products])', and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."}

Can I make LINQ invoke these methods to build the query?
Or is there a better way to query and map these objects without grabbing 50+ tables of unnecessary data for hundreds of clients?

**UPDATE**

User *Tuco* mentioned that I could try looking into expression trees. After reading up on them for a bit I came up with this.

```
public static Expression<Func<Product, ProductDTO>> test = prod =>
        new ProductDTO()
        {
            ID= prod.ID,
            Date= prod.Date,
            //etc...
        };
```

And use it as such.

```
Products = client.Products.Select(prod => test.Compile()(prod)),
```

But running this I receive this error.

> The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities

Comment: EF doesn't return all the graph by default, you have to use Include for each navigation property

Comment: Isn't this called lazy loading, and isn't it enabled by default?

Comment: Yes, but it won't pull the data until you request it

Comment: What you're trying to do needs Expression Trees

Comment: Why do you "need" to use mappers? You can't put user-defined functions into other queries in general, but you can use something like LINQKit to do lambda expansions from user-defined functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close with your 2nd approach!

Let's say you define the projection of the product entity to the DTO (the mapper as you call it) like you did:

```
Expression<Func<Product, ProductDTO>> productProjection = prod => new ProductDTO
{
    ID = prod.ID,
    DateOfTransaction = prod.Date
    // ...
};
```

and the projection of the client entity to it's DTO like this (slightly simpler, but logically equivalent to what you did):

```
Expression<Func<Client, ClientDTO>> clientProjection = client => new ClientDTO
{
    ID = client.ClientID,
    FirstName = client.FirstName,
    // ...
    Products = client.Products.Select(productProjection.Compile()).ToList(),
    // ...
};
```

The compiler let's you do so, but the queryable will not understand that. However what you have achieved is that the `productProjection` is somehow contained in the expression tree. All you have to do is some expression manipulation.

If you look at the subtree the compiler builds for the argument to `.Select` you'll find a `MethodCallExpression` - the call to `.Compile()`. It's `.Object`  expression - the thing that is to be compiled - is a `MemberExpression` accessing a field named `productProjection`(!) on an `ConstantExpression` containing an instance of an oddly named compiler generated closure class.

So: Find `.Compile()` calls and replace them with what *would* be compiled, ending up with the very expression tree you had in your original version.

I'm maintaining a helper class for expression stuff called `Express`. (See another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45307512/5758243) that deals with `.Compile().Invoke(...)` for a similar situation).

```
clientProjection = Express.Uncompile(clientProjection);
var clientList = dbClients.Select(clientProjection).ToList();
```

Here's the relevant snipped of the `Express` class.

```
public static class Express
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Replace .Compile() calls to lambdas with the lambdas themselves.
    /// </summary>
    public static Expression<TDelegate> Uncompile<TDelegate>(Expression<TDelegate> lambda)
    => (Expression<TDelegate>)UncompileVisitor.Singleton.Visit(lambda);

    /// <summary>
    /// Evaluate an expression to a value.
    /// </summary>
    private static object GetValue(Expression x)
    {
        switch (x.NodeType)
        {
            case ExpressionType.Constant:
                return ((ConstantExpression)x).Value;
            case ExpressionType.MemberAccess:
                var xMember = (MemberExpression)x;
                var instance = xMember.Expression == null ? null : GetValue(xMember.Expression);
                switch (xMember.Member.MemberType)
                {
                    case MemberTypes.Field:
                        return ((FieldInfo)xMember.Member).GetValue(instance);
                    case MemberTypes.Property:
                        return ((PropertyInfo)xMember.Member).GetValue(instance);
                    default:
                        throw new Exception(xMember.Member.MemberType + "???");
                }
            default:
                // NOTE: it would be easy to compile and invoke the expression, but it's intentionally not done. Callers can always pre-evaluate and pass a member of a closure.
                throw new NotSupportedException("Only constant, field or property supported.");
        }
    }

    private sealed class UncompileVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        public static UncompileVisitor Singleton { get; } = new UncompileVisitor();
        private UncompileVisitor() { }

        protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
        {
            if (node.Method.Name != "Compile" || node.Arguments.Count != 0 || node.Object == null || !typeof(LambdaExpression).IsAssignableFrom(node.Object.Type))
                return base.VisitMethodCall(node);
            var lambda = (LambdaExpression)GetValue(node.Object);
            return lambda;

            // alternatively recurse on the lambda if it possibly could contain .Compile()s
            // return Visit(lambda); // recurse on the lambda
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use LINQKit to expand user-defined lambda functions into the lambdas needed in the query:

https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit