# Converting Linq nested Any within Where to a Generic Expression

Tags: c#, linq, linq-expressions

I'm trying to convert the following using Expressions so I could engineer it to be more generic and work over different collections with differing properties:

```
var roleId = 1;

users.Where(u => u.Roles.Any(ur => ur.Id == roleId));
```

I have created an "Any" expression but I'm unsure how to move this within an Expression.Call to "Where":

```
var predicateParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ListItem), "ur");
var left = Expression.Property(predicateParameter, "Id");
var right = Expression.Constant(roleId, typeof(int));
var expression = Expression.Equal(left, right);            
var anyCheckFunction = Expression.Lambda<Func<ListItem, bool>>(expression, predicateParameter);

Expression<Func<UserDto, Expression<Func<int, int, int>>, Expression<Func<int>>>> power2 =
                        (o, f) => Expression.Lambda<Func<int>>(Expression.Invoke(f, Expression.Constant(o), Expression.Constant(o)));
            
var anyMethod2 = Expression.Call(
                                anyMethod,
                                users.First().UserRoles.AsQueryable().Expression,
                                anyCheckFunction);
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

You can use generic classes and methods.
For example:

```
public class Repository<T>
{
    public List<T> GetByPredicate(Func<T, bool> predicate, IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        return items.Where(predicate).ToList();
    }
}


var repository = new Repository<User>();

var result = repository.GetByPredicate(u => u.Roles.Any(ur => ur.Id == roleId), users).ToList();
```

You can replace items with the database context, or you can use a collection that you fill in yourself.