# Is it possible to use Func<entity> in Where method to hot swap them?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I'm making a hot swappable filter for my entities that depend on a mode selected. I'd like to be able to call something like

```
list.Where(e => Filter.Func(e)).ToList();
```

With this

```
public class Filter() {
    public Func<CollectedDataRecord, bool> Func = (o) => true;
    //code that assigns other Func's depending on case
}
```

Basically that's it. But I get 'The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.'

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284912/the-linq-expression-node-type-invoke-is-not-supported-in-linq-to-entities) But I didn't get the solution.

Is it possible of I should make it in a different way. May be make Table Functions in SQL?

Comment: You mean something like this? `Expression<Func<Entity, bool>> wherePredicate = p => p.Mode == Mode.FirstMode; list.Where(wherePredicate).ToList()`.

Comment: You should understand solution in a link you posted instead of finding a new way. The referenced link contains the best solution for your problem. Learn about `Expression` and `Func` and how predicates work and implement solution from the link.

Comment: what is the return type of `Filter.Func`?

Comment: Yeah, now I get it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `Filter.Func(e)` method returns an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`, and not a `Func<T, bool>` (since you are using EF) then you should be able to do the following.

```
var predicate = Filter.Func(e);
list.Where(predicate).ToList();
```

Explicitly getting the predicate first forces EF not to include the execution of the `Filter.Func(e)` in the expression, which EF cannot handle, which is why you get the exception you're getting.

Comment: Brilliant. Exactly what I expected to see. I guess I wrote Expression in a wrong way, when tried to Ctrl + . to resolve missing using at first time.

Answer (score 0):

I think your Func would look like below

```
Func<listObjectType, bool> FilterFunc()
{
     Func<listObjectType, bool> s = delegate (listObjectType obj)
     {
           return obj == ""; //Here your code for comparison should go
     };
     return s;
}

list.Where(FilterFunc()).ToList();
```

or if you have Func available directly

```
Func<listObjectType, bool> s = delegate (listObjectType obj)
{
     return obj == ""; //Here your code for comparison should go
};

list.Where(s).ToList();
```

Comment: Last one. Thanks, but the question was answered. I just needed to change Func<CollectedDataRecord, bool> Func to Expression<Func<T, bool>> Func. And it works brilliantly. As I intended.