# C# Dynamic Linq: Implement "Like" in The Where Clause

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, dynamic, dynamic-linq

So I want to make a general sorter for my data. I have this code to get data from the database which will extract the data only which contains `value`.

```
using System.Linq.Dynamic;

public static IQueryable<object> SortList(string searchString, Type modelType, 
    IQueryable<object> model)
{
    ....

    string toStringPredicate = type == typeof(string) ? propertyName + 
        ".Contains(@0)" : propertyName + ".ToString().Contains(@0)";
    model = model.Where(propertyName + " != NULL AND " + toStringPredicate, value);
}
```

The model is this:

```
public class ManageSubscriberItems
{
    public int? UserId { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public Guid SubscriberId { get; set; }
}
```

When I call:

```
models = (IQueryable<ManageSubscriberItems>)EcommerceCMS.Helpers.FilterHelper
    .SortList(searchString, typeof(ManageSubscriberItems), models);

if(models.Any())
```

It throws this error:

> "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String
>   ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store
>   expression."

---

### EDIT

I found the problem, but I still cannot fix it. So if the property is not `string`, it will throw an error when calling `.ToString().Contains()`.

```
model = model.Where(propertyName + " != NULL AND " + propertyName + 
    ".ToString().Contains(@0)", value);
```

What I want is to implement `LIKE` in the query. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.stringconvert?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#overloads , i don't think you can use ToString() in LinQ or in EF. What you could do is to make a property/variable and set its value .ToString() before your query, than use that property/variable (and remove the .ToString()).  Something along these lines: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/exception-linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-tostring

Comment: Is this LINQ to SQL or LINQ to EF? `ToString` seems to work for me in LINQ to SQL statically or dynamically.

Comment: If the type is numeric, you could try `SqlFunctions.StringConvert` instead.

Comment: @NetMage This is Linq to SQL in `IQueryable` form. Probably it will work if I called `ToList()` or `ToEnumerable()` first, but I do not want to process this in the memory. I tried using `SqlFunctions.StringConvert` in the dynamic expression (written in string) and it gives me an error. Right now I can only check if it is numeric, I use `==`, if it is string I use `.Contains()`. This is not what I want. It is not behaving like `Like` operator.

Comment: Which version from EF are you using?

Comment: Maybe [DbFunctions.Like()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.like) may help you

Answer (score 15):

If you use [System.Linq.Dynamic.Core](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core) with **EF Core**, you have an option to use

```cs
var q = context.Cars.Where(config, "DynamicFunctions.Like(Brand, \"%a%\")");
```

See this link for an example:
https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/blob/6fc7fcc43b248940560a0728c4d181e191f9eec1/src-console/ConsoleAppEF2.1.1/Program.cs#L117

And I just tested in linqpad connecting to a real database, and code like this  just works?

```cs
var result1 = Entity1s.Where("Url != NULL AND it.Url.Contains(@0)", "e");
```

**[UPDATE 2019-04-17]]**

In case you don't know the type, you can cast it to **object** and then cast that to a **string**.

Code:

```cs
var r = Entity1s.Select("string(object(Rating))").Where("Contains(@0)", "6");
```

Comment: I am not using EF Core. Contains() can only be used by string type object, other than that throws error.

Comment: Much appreciated. I couldn't find this functionality until I saw this comment. Works perfectly for efcore

Answer (score 4):

so the problem here is that **IQueryable** thing happens on the **SQL** server not in C#... so **SQL** server doesn't know anything about **.toString()** method. 
so => and **Like operator** it self works on strings.. so it's nvarchar and varchar data types in SQL server. 
I could give You an example of how to achieve it if you could tell me more about your problem and what You want to achieve. 
could do a sample.

Answer (score 0):

You already have a "Like" in Linq that can run in the database and works with strings, it's called "IndexOf":

```cs
 ((IQueryable)model).Where(m => m.Property.IndexOf(searchString) == 1);
```

According to MSDN:
[IndexOf(string)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_IndexOf_System_String_)

'*The zero-based index position of value if that string is found, or -1 if it is not. If value is Empty, the return value is 0.*'

Answer (score 0):

> So I want to make a general sorter for my data.

instead of fixing ['invoke issue'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284912/the-linq-expression-node-type-invoke-is-not-supported-in-linq-to-entities), general way should use generics, like

```
public static IQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, 
                                       string property,
                                       bool asc = true) where T : class
{
    //STEP 1: Validate MORE!
    var searchProperty = typeof(T).GetProperty(property);
    if (searchProperty == null) throw new ArgumentException("property");

     ....

    //STEP 2: Create the OrderBy property selector
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "o");
    var selectorExpr = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Property(parameter, property), parameter)        

    //STEP 3: Update the IQueryable expression to include OrderBy
    Expression queryExpr = source.Expression;
    queryExpr = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), asc ? "OrderBy" : "OrderByDescending",
                                  new Type[] { source.ElementType, searchProperty.PropertyType },
                                 queryExpr, 
                                selectorExpr);

    return source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(queryExpr);
}
```

having property name string and direction usually used for making 'column sorting' on data.

Next are relation predicates are coming, and 'Linq.Dynamic' seems reasonable when doing from scratch, but there is generic and canonical form [exists](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx).