# C# merge/combine expressions

Tags: c#, expression, expression-trees

With the following example classes (which could map to a database table):

```cs
class Package
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }

    public static Expression<Func<Package, bool>> IsActive =>
        x => x.Enabled;
}

class Schedule
{
    public DateTimeOffset Start { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset End { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }

    public static Expression<Func<Schedule, bool>> IsActive =>
        x => x.Enabled && x.Start > DateTimeOffset.Now;
}
```

and the following (which could be a join table):

```cs
class SchedulePackage
{
    public Package Package { get; init; }
    public Schedule Schedule { get; init; }
}
```

How can I merge the two expressions with `AndAlso`? An active `SchedulePackage` is one that both its package and schedule are active (whatever those mean). So, in order to avoid code duplication, it's better to reuse the `IsActive` logic of each entity.

Let's say I have the following:

```cs
public static Expression<Func<SchedulePackage, bool>> IsActive =>
    x => x.Package.Enabled && x.Schedule.Enabled && x.Schedule.Start > DateTimeOffset.Now;
```

Now if I update the package logic

```cs
public static Expression<Func<Package, bool>> IsActive =>
    x => x.Enabled && x.Price > 0;
```

I have to update `SchedulePackage` as well:

```cs
public static Expression<Func<SchedulePackage, bool>> IsActive =>
    x => x.Package.Enabled && x.Package.Price > 0 && x.Schedule.Enabled && x.Schedule.Start > DateTimeOffset.Now;
```

Comment: Isn't it possible to turn `IsActive` into a bool property? e.g. `public bool IsActive  => Enabled && Start > DateTimeOffset.Now` ? It is then trivial to `and` the two respective props together.

Comment: @psnx Then it'll just fail at runtime as the query provider won't know what to do with the property.

Comment: @Parsa99 - it's not shown in the linked duplicate, but you can use [`ExpressionVisitor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/advanced-topics/expression-trees/expression-trees-translating?redirectedfrom=MSDN#create-a-modified-copy) to create a modified copy of the body of `Schedule.IsActive` and `Package.IsActive` that replaces the parameter expression with some other expression, e.g. one that accesses the properties of `SchedulePackage`.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/KueMiX for a demo.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: @dbc That's exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: @Parsa99 - should I vote to reopen the question then?

Comment: @dbc Yes, the duplication link has nothing to do with my question and your answer.

Comment: @Parsa99 - OK, done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of Entity Framework (or other LINQ to Entities applications) it is generally not possible for one expression to **invoke** another for reasons explained in *["The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities" - stumped!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5284912/3744182)*.  Instead what you can do is subclass [`ExpressionVisitor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/advanced-topics/expression-trees/expression-trees-translating#create-a-modified-copy) to create modified copies of the bodies of `Schedule.IsActive` and `Package.IsActive` that take `SchedulePackage.Schedule` and `SchedulePackage.Package` as inputs, then compose them with a binary `&&` expression for the final result.

To accomplish this, first create the following extension methods for composing functional expressions:

```
public static partial class ExpressionExtensions
{
    // Compose two Func<Tx, Ty> expressions with compatible generic parameters into a third.
    public static Expression<Func<T1, TResult>> Compose<T1, T2, TResult>(this Expression<Func<T2, TResult>> outer, Expression<Func<T1, T2>> inner) =>
        Expression.Lambda<Func<T1, TResult>>(
            new ParameterReplacer((outer.Parameters[0], inner.Body)).Visit(outer.Body), 
            false, inner.Parameters[0]);    

    // Compose a Func<T2, T3, TResult> expression with compatible Func<T1, T2> and Func<T1, T3> expressions to obtain a Func<T1, TResult> expression.
    public static Expression<Func<T1, TResult>> Compose<T1, T2, T3, TResult>(this Expression<Func<T2, T3, TResult>> outer, Expression<Func<T1, T2>> inner1, Expression<Func<T1, T3>> inner2)
    {
        var inner2body = new ParameterReplacer((inner2.Parameters[0], (Expression)inner1.Parameters[0])).Visit(inner2.Body);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T1, TResult>>(
            new ParameterReplacer((outer.Parameters[0], inner1.Body), (outer.Parameters[1], inner2body)).Visit(outer.Body), 
            false, inner1.Parameters[0]);   
    }
}

class ParameterReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
{
    // Replace formal parameters (e.g. of a lambda body) with some containing expression in scope.
    readonly Dictionary<ParameterExpression, Expression> parametersToReplace;
    public ParameterReplacer(params (ParameterExpression parameter, Expression replacement) [] parametersToReplace) =>
        this.parametersToReplace = parametersToReplace.ToDictionary(p => p.parameter, p => p.replacement);
    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression p) => 
        parametersToReplace.TryGetValue(p, out var e) ? e : base.VisitParameter(p);
}
```

And now you can write `SchedulePackage.IsActive` as follows:

```
static Lazy<Expression<Func<SchedulePackage, bool>>> IsActiveExpression = new(static () => {
    var left = Package.IsActive.Compose((SchedulePackage sp) => sp.Package);
    var right = Schedule.IsActive.Compose((SchedulePackage sp) => sp.Schedule);
    Expression<Func<bool, bool, bool>> binary = (b1, b2) => b1 && b2;
    return binary.Compose(left, right);
});

public static Expression<Func<SchedulePackage, bool>> IsActive => IsActiveExpression.Value;
```

The resulting expression looks like:

```
sp => (sp.Package.Enabled AndAlso (sp.Schedule.Enabled AndAlso (sp.Schedule.Start > DateTimeOffset.Now)))
```

Note that the inner `IsActive` expressions have been inlined rather than invoked.

I am lazily constructing the expression once and reusing it purely for performance reasons.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iiWU6g).