# Replacing the parameter name in the Body of an Expression

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

I'm trying to dynamically build up expressions based on a Specification object.

I've created an ExpressionHelper class that has a private Expression like so:

```
private Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression;

public ExpressionHelper()
{
    expression = (Expression<Func<T, bool>>)(a => true);
}
```

And then some easy methods as follows:

```
public void And(Expression<Func<T,bool>> exp);
```

I'm struggling with the body of the And method. I basically want to rip the body out of `exp`, replace all the parameters with those in `expression` and then append it to the end of the `expression` body as and AndAlso.

I've done this:

```
var newBody = Expression.And(expression.Body,exp.Body);

expression = expression.Update(newBody, expression.Parameters);
```

But that ends up with my expression looking like this:

```
{ a => e.IsActive && e.IsManaged }
```

Is there a simpler way to do this? Or how can I rip out those e's and replace them with a's?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The simplest approach here is `Expression.Invoke`, for example:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> AndAlso<T>(
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> x, Expression<Func<T, bool>> y)
{
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
        Expression.AndAlso(x.Body, Expression.Invoke(y, x.Parameters)),
        x.Parameters);
}
```

This works fine for LINQ-to-Objects and LINQ-to-SQL, but isn't supported by EF. For EF you'll need to use a visitor to rewrite the tree, sadly.

Using the code from: [Combining two lambda expressions in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717444/combining-two-lamba-expressions-in-c/1720642#1720642)

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> AndAlso<T>(
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> x, Expression<Func<T, bool>> y)
{
    var newY = new ExpressionRewriter().Subst(y.Parameters[0], x.Parameters[0]).Inline().Apply(y.Body);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
        Expression.AndAlso(x.Body, newY),
        x.Parameters);
}
```

Or in .NET 4.0, using `ExpressionVisitor`:

```
class ParameterVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly ReadOnlyCollection<ParameterExpression> from, to;
    public ParameterVisitor(
        ReadOnlyCollection<ParameterExpression> from,
        ReadOnlyCollection<ParameterExpression> to)
    {
        if(from == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("from");
        if(to == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("to");
        if(from.Count != to.Count) throw new InvalidOperationException(
             "Parameter lengths must match");
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }
    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < from.Count; i++)
        {
            if (node == from[i]) return to[i];
        }
        return node;
    }
}
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> AndAlso<T>(
      Expression<Func<T, bool>> x, Expression<Func<T, bool>> y)
{
    var newY = new ParameterVisitor(y.Parameters, x.Parameters)
              .VisitAndConvert(y.Body, "AndAlso");
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
        Expression.AndAlso(x.Body, newY),
        x.Parameters);
}
```

Comment: Dammit, JUST got Invoke working in memory and was testing on EF when this happened. Thanks.

Comment: @robert IIRC Invoke doesn't work on EF, so you'll need to use the second version

Comment: Your approach works but now I have your amazingly complex and untested ReWriter in my codebase. :( Seeing how smart it looks, I'm going to keep it till I understand it!

Comment: 4.0 also has an inbuilt ExpressionVisitor that might be worth a look - if you are on 4.0!

Comment: @robert - added a version that doesn't need this

Comment: I would recommend asserting that `to.Count == from.Count`.

Comment: You want `Count`; `Length` is for strings and arrays.