# variable '' of type '' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

Tags: c#, expression-trees

Well, the following code is self-explaining; I want to combine two expressions into one using `And` operator. The last line causes rune-time the error:

> Additional information: variable 'y' of type 'System.String' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

Code:

```
Expression<Func<string, bool>> e1 = y => y.Length < 100;
Expression<Func<string, bool>> e2 = y => y.Length < 200;

var e3 = Expression.And(e1.Body, e2.Body);

var e4 = Expression.Lambda<Func<string, bool>>(e3, e1.Parameters.ToArray());
e4.Compile(); // <--- causes run-time error
```

Comment: Don't claim code is self-explaining. Explain what you expect it to do. Do you want `e1` and `e2` to be `and`ed and to operate on one and the same input parameter?

Comment: The variable `y` used in `e2` isn't defined - it may have the same name as the one in `e1`, but that's not how they're matched.

Comment: @CodeCaster What you asked about is exactly mentioned in the question. Thank you.

Comment: Hans, no, it isn't. You only mention "combine", you don't mention you want both `y` parameters to refer to the same parameter. Notice the "and" in that comment. You're welcome.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Thanks everybody collaborated.

As @dasblinkenlight pointed out the two parameters in the two expressions are not the same. Reason? Well, it is the compiler trick. When compiling, it creates a class for each expression and name each parameter something like xxx1, xxx2,... completely different from the original names.

And the answer for .Net 4.0+:

[How to Combine two lambdas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6736505/how-to-combine-two-lambdas/6736589#6736589)

Answer (score 28):

As indicated in the other answer, you have two expressions where both have a parameter named `y`. Those don't automatically relate to each other.

To properly compile your expression, you need to specify both source expression's parameters:

```
Expression<Func<string, bool>> e1 = (y => y.Length > 0);
Expression<Func<string, bool>> e2 = (y => y.Length < 5);

var e3 = Expression.And(e1.Body, e2.Body);

// (string, string) by adding both expressions' parameters.
var e4 = Expression.Lambda<Func<string, string, bool>>(e3, new[] 
{ 
    e1.Parameters[0], 
    e2.Parameters[0] 
});

Func<string, string, bool> compiledExpression = e4.Compile();

bool result = compiledExpression("Foo", "Foo");
```

Of course, you'd want an expression that combines both expressions with only one parameter. You can rebuild the expressions like this:

```
ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "y");
var lengthPropertyExpression = Expression.Property(param, "Length");

var e1 = Expression.GreaterThan(lengthPropertyExpression, Expression.Constant(0));
var e2 = Expression.LessThan(lengthPropertyExpression, Expression.Constant(5));

var e3 = Expression.AndAlso(e1, e2);

var e4 = Expression.Lambda<Func<string, bool>>(e3, new[] { param });

Func<string, bool> compiledExpression = e4.Compile();

bool result = compiledExpression("Foo");
```

As for your comment that you don't want to rebuild the expression, but do it on an existing expression's body and parameters: this works using `ExpressionRewriter` from [Combining two lambda expressions in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717444/combining-two-lambda-expressions-in-c-sharp/1720642#1720642) and `AndAlso` from [Replacing the parameter name in the Body of an Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5430996/replacing-the-parameter-name-in-the-body-of-an-expression):

```
Expression<Func<string, bool>> e1 = (y => y.Length > 0);
Expression<Func<string, bool>> e2 = (z => z.Length < 10);

var e3 = ParameterReplacer.AndAlso<string>(e1, e2);

Func<string, bool> compiledExpression = e3.Compile();

bool result = compiledExpression("Foo");
```

Comment: Thanks, my problem is that the two expressions are passed into a combining method and I'm not aware of the body and really I don't want to get involved, although I asked a simpler question.

Answer (score 24):

The problem is that parameter expression objects that represents variable `y` in expressions `e1` and `e2` are different. The fact that the two variables are named the same and have the same type does not matter: `e1.Parameters.First()` and `e2.Parameters.First()` is not the same object.

This causes the problem that you see: only `e1`'s parameter `y` is available to `Lambda<>`, while `e2`'s parameter `y` is out of scope.

To fix this problem use `Expression` APIs to create `e1` and `e2`. This way you would be able to share the parameter expression across them, thus eliminating the problem of scope.

Comment: What kind of API should I use, would you please help?

Comment: @Hans Use the same API that you are using in the second half the way the other answer is showing. I assume that you are building these expressions in your code. If this assumption is incorrect, and someone else is passing you expressions `e1` and `e2`, you need to replace parameters by walking the expression tree (the last part of the other answer explains how to do that, too).

Answer (score 0):

Another case where you'll get this error is when using `BlockExpression` with local variables.

`Expression.Block` has an overload with a `variables` parameter, and you need to pass in your local variable references to this parameter:

```cs
Expression.Block(
    variables: new[] { myLocalVar1, myLocalVar2 },
    expressions: /* some collection of expressions that use myLocalVar1 and myLocalVar2 */
);
```