# variable 'c' of type 'MyClass' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

Tags: c#, .net

I want to put an query inside an expression for a filter.

I have a switch and for a specific case I need to do a different validation.

```
private Expression<Func<MyClass, bool>> Filter(int idStatus)
{
    switch (idStatus)
    {
        case case1:
            return c => c.Status == (int)MyEnum.Status1 && c.Active;
        case case2:
            return c => c.Status == (int)MyEnum.Status2 && c.Active;
        case case3:
            return c => c.Status == (int)MyEnum.Status3 && c.Active;
        case case4:
            return c => _myService.FindByMyClassId(c.Id) != null && c.Active;
    }
}
```

MyClass:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class MyClass //Process class
    {
        public virtual int Id{ get; set; }
        public virtual string ProcessCode { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime Created{ get; set; };
        public virtual int Status{ get; set; }
        public virtual int IdUser{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

MyClass mapping with Nhibernate:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
    <class name="MyNamespace.MyClass,MyNamespace" table="my_class" lazy="true" mutable="false">

    <id name="Id" column="id" type="int32">
      <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property column="process_code" type="String" name="ProcessCode" />
    <property column="created" type="DateTime" name="Created" />
    <property column="id_user" type="Int32" name="IdUser" />
    <property column="id_status" type="Int32" name="Status" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

This method is called in the main filter method:

```
query = query.Where(Filter(Convert.ToInt32(filters["Status"])));
```

With the normal cases the code runs perfectly but, in this specific case (case4) i'm getting the error:

> variable 'c' of type 'MyClass' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

Comment: Have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30556911/variable-of-type-referenced-from-scope-but-it-is-not-defined.

Comment: I have, apparently this error is really generic. In that case the problem was two expressions with the same parameter name, but this doesn't apply to my problem.

Comment: Can you post 'MyClass'

Comment: Is the `query` related to Entity Framework?

Comment: The query is related to Nhibernate.

Comment: As i remember right, NHibernate tries to translate the query into SQL but should not be able because of the service call. Did you tried the query without your filter method and added the predicate by hand like `query.Where(c => _myService.FindByMyClassId(c.Id) != null && c.Active)`? The error should be the same and indicate that this type of predicate is not working. In earlier version of NHibernate it threw some `NotSupportedException` or something like this, that was more meaningful.

Comment: I don't think that it is possible to achieve it the way you want. If you don't have to many entities in your table, you could materialize them beforehand and then add your predicate so that it runs in your application. The downside is that you need to request all entities and then filter them. Or you need to rework your service to return a list of valid ids and then put them in your query.

Comment: Perhaps the issue lies in your `FindByMyClass` method or your `.ID` property?

Comment: Rabban, that's what I thought, I"ll probabbly need to make a query (q2) listing all entities in the table using the service and then remove all the entities in the previus query that are not in q2. As you said, when I tried ```query.Where(c => _myService.FindByMyClassId(c.Id) != null && c.Active)``` the result is the same error.

Comment: xTwisteDx, I don't think that there's any issue with the class, i've been using it for some time and this is the first time i'm getting any error.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for the help.