# C# Expression Tree compile issue

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-mvc

I have the following Expression tree which gives me an error when I compile the expression tree.

```
        string tenantId = "tst user";

        Expression<Func<MongoIdentityUser, bool>> filterToUse = t => t.IsActive == true && t.IsApproved == true;
        var expConst = Expression.Constant(tenantId);
        var paramExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(MongoIdentityUser), "t");
        var callExp = Expression.PropertyOrField(paramExp, "TenantId");
        var equalExp = Expression.Equal(callExp,Expression.Constant(null));
        var equalExp2 = Expression.Equal(callExp, expConst);
        var conditionExp = Expression.Condition(equalExp, Expression.Constant(true), equalExp2);
        var AndExp = Expression.AndAlso(filterToUse.Body, conditionExp);

        var lambdaExp1 = Expression.Lambda<Func<MongoIdentityUser, bool>>(AndExp, paramExp);
       
        Console.WriteLine(lambdaExp1.Compile());

The generated expression is as follows

t => (((t.IsActive == True) AndAlso (t.IsApproved == True)) AndAlso IIF((t.TenantId == null), True, (t.TenantId == "tst user")))
```

**But when I called lambdaExp1.Compile() it gives me the following error**
[image]

Comment: Did you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30557647/1543596) answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace your

```
var paramExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(MongoIdentityUser), "t");
```

with

```
var paramExp= filterToUse.Parameters[0];
```

Then it should work.

You can't reference the parameter of the Expression `filterToUse` as `"t"`
(Would that instead try to capture a local scope variable called `t`?)

Answer (score 0):

The `t` parameter in `filterToUse` and `paramExp` are treated as different ones by `LambdaCompiler` (`ParameterExpression` does not override `Equals` and `GetHashcode` and is used as key in [`Definitions`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Linq.Expressions/System/Linq/Expressions/Compiler/VariableBinder.cs,248) dictionary).

If you have Entity Framework Core added to your project you can use [`ReplacingExpressionVisitor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.query.replacingexpressionvisitor?view=efcore-3.1) to replace `t` with `paramExp`:

```
var filter = ReplacingExpressionVisitor.Replace(filterToUse.Parameters.First(), paramExp, filterToUse.Body); 
var AndExp = Expression.AndAlso(filter, conditionExp);
....
```

If it is not available for you, you can write your own one. Or use `filterToUse.Parameters.First()` (since you have only one expression to extend/combine) as your `paramExp`, i.e.:

```
var paramExp = filterToUse.Parameters.First();
```