# Combine Generic ICollection<T> Expression with an Any Accepting a Generic Predicate

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, linq-to-entities, expression-trees

I'm trying to figure out how to combine the following Expressions:

```
Expression<Func<TParent, ICollection<TChild>>> childSelector = p => p.Children;

Expression<Func<TChild, bool>> childPredicate = c => c.NameLast.StartsWith("V");

var anyExpression = childSelector <------> .Any(childPredicate);
```

The "<------>" is the part I don't know what to do with. I'm using LINQKit, I just can't figure out how to combine these expressions.

Can someone give me a hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the [answer to my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717444/combining-two-lamba-expressions-in-c/1720642#1720642)

```
childSelector.Combine(p => p.AsQueryable().Any<TEntity>(this.Predicate), true)
```

This is how the code turned out.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% clear on what you want anyExpression to be, but this is my best guess.

```
Expression<Func<TParent, bool>> anyExpression = p => p.Select(childselector).Any(childPredicate);
```

Comment: This may work in other cases, and I did actually try this. While it did build, it gave me an error at runtime regarding the variable "p" not being defined. Which made sense, with the way I was building the predicate in other places in my code. Thanks for your answer, hopefully it will help someone here.

Answer (score 0):

you can do childselector(parent).Any(childPredicate) where parent is a TParent instance.

Comment: Thanks for the response, however, I won't have an instance of a parent until much later in the program execution. I'm trying to build an expression try across multiple classes, so I'm a few levels removed from the actual querying.