# How to Combine two lambdas

Tags: c#, .net, expression-trees

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [combining two lamba expressions in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717444/combining-two-lamba-expressions-in-c)

I have two following expressions:

```
Expression<Func<string, bool>> expr1 = s => s.Length == 5;
Expression<Func<string, bool>> expr2 = s => s == "someString";
```

Now I need to combine them with OR. Something like this:

```
Expression.Or(expr1, expr2)
```

Is there any way to make this similar to above code way like:

```
expr1 || expr2
```

I understand in this example I can just combine it in the first place:

```
Expression<Func<string, bool>> expr = s => s.Length == 5 || s == "someString"
```

but I can't do it in my real code as I get expr1 and expr2 as arguments to the method.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

To complete Eric's answer, using the new `ExpressionVisitor` introduced in .NET 4 rather than a custom rewriter:

```
internal class ParameterReplacer : ExpressionVisitor {
    private readonly ParameterExpression _parameter;

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node) {
        return base.VisitParameter(_parameter);
    }

    internal ParameterReplacer(ParameterExpression parameter) {
        _parameter = parameter;
    }
}

class Program {

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Expression<Func<string, bool>> expr1 = s => s.Length == 5;
        Expression<Func<string, bool>> expr2 = s => s == "someString";
        var paramExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string));
        var exprBody = Expression.Or(expr1.Body, expr2.Body);
        exprBody = (BinaryExpression) new ParameterReplacer(paramExpr).Visit(exprBody);
        var finalExpr = Expression.Lambda<Func<string, bool>>(exprBody, paramExpr);
    }

}
```

Comment: Instead of writing your own `ParameterReplacer`, you can use the built-in

`Expression newBody = ReplacingExpressionVisitor.Replace(expression.Parameters.Single(), paramExpr, expression.Body);`

Answer (score 26):

The problem is that the "s" parameters in each lambda have the same name and same type, but they are different parameters.  Parameters have *reference identity*, not *value identity*.  Simply combining the two bodies of the existing expression trees into a third expression tree effectively makes:

```
s => s1.Length == 5 || s2 == "somestring"
```

which doesn't make any sense. What you want to do is write a visitor that does a search-and-replace of the parameter s with a *new* parameter that you will then use as the parameter to the new lambda expression.

See this related question for more details:

[Combining two lambda expressions in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717444/combining-two-lamba-expressions-in-c/1717608#1717608)