# Combine two lambda expressions with inner expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression, predicate

I have the next class structure:

```
    public class Order
    {
        public User User { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Authentication
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }      
    }

    public class User
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Authentication> Auths { get; set; }
    }
```

I'm trying to build an expression at runtime to search entities by User.Name, Order.Name or User.Auths.Email

There are three expressions I'm trying to combine:

```
    Expression<Func<Order, bool>> usernameExpression = order => order.Name.Contains(searchValue);
    Expression<Func<Order, bool>> nameExpression = order => order.User.Name.Contains(searchValue);
    Expression<Func<Order, bool>> emailExpression = order => order.User.Auths.Any(auth => auth.Email.Contains(searchValue));
```

I successfully combined two first expressions using ParameterReplacer from this thread: [How to Combine two lambdas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6736505/how-to-combine-two-lambdas/6736589#6736589)

However, when combining resulting expression with email expression I get the next error:

```
Property 'System.String Email' is not defined for type Order'
```

Looks like the scope doesn't know anything about inner 'auth' parameter. 
Is it possible to creeate the expression without rebuilding it from scratch?

Comment: Post your attempt at the combination

Comment: You say that you want to combine the, but *how* do you want to combine them?  What expression are you trying to end up with?

Comment: @Servy, I was trying to combine them using OrAlso\AndAlso clause. The link to the helper from Ivan's post resolved the issue

Comment: @Refraction That doesn't answer the question of how, specifically, you want to combine them, and what, exactly, you want the examples you provided to produce.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ParameterReplacer you have used is too simplified and blindly replaces **every** parameter.

Use this instead:

```
public static class ExpressionUtils
{
    public static Expression ReplaceParameter(this Expression expression, ParameterExpression source, Expression target)
    {
        return new ParameterReplacer { Source = source, Target = target }.Visit(expression);
    }

    class ParameterReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        public ParameterExpression Source;
        public Expression Target;
        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
        {
            return node == Source ? Target : base.VisitParameter(node);
        }
    }
}
```

Or use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36246162/establish-a-link-between-two-lists-in-linq-to-entities-where-clause/36247259#36247259) or [this](https://petemontgomery.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/a-universal-predicatebuilder/) predicate builder helpers.

Comment: expression helper from the first link perfectly fixed the issue. Thank you

Comment: @infinitesimal Something like in here https://stackoverflow.com/a/69470727/5202563