# Replace parameter into expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression

Given:

```
var paramA = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "a");
```

and:

```
Expression<Func<string, bool>> expr = b => b == "Something";
```

Is there anyway to replace `b` by `paramA` into the expression `expr`?

Comment: Yes, use `ExpressionVisitor`. There are many examples of parameter replacers on SO, here are mine https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A5202563+ParameterReplacer

Comment: Do you need a replacement, or you simply want an `Expression<Func<string,bool>>` that does the same thing as `expr`, of which `a` is a parameter?

Comment: Hi @dasblinkenlight, a replacement or a new expression could work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can walk the expression tree of `expr`, and replace all occurrences of `b` with `paramA` using the approach described in this Q&A: ["Combine two lambda expressions with inner expression"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36651409/335858).

However, if you simply need a lambda expression that uses `paramA` as its parameter, it is easier to make a lambda that wraps `expr` instead:

```
var res = (Expression<Func<string,bool>>)Expression.Lambda(
    Expression.Invoke(expr, paramA)
,   paramA
);
```

Comment: Thx @dasblinkenlight !

Comment: I always forget about this approach (mainly because it's not supported in EF which I use exclusively :) +1