# LINQ expressions can not be translated to Sql when combining specifications in Specification Pattern

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core, specification-pattern

I am using the Specification pattern to perform db filtering, and avoid doing it on memory ([I roughly followed this article](https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/posts/specification-pattern-c-implementation/)). My base specification class is something like this:

```
    public abstract class Specification<T> : ISpecification<T>{

    public abstract Expression<Func<T, bool>> FilterExpr();

    public bool IsSatisfied(T entity)
    {
        Func<T, bool> func = this.FilterExpr().Compile();
        return func(entity);
    }

    public Specification<T> And(Specification<T> otherSpec)
    {
        return new CombinedSpecification<T>(this, otherSpec);
    }
}
```

From this base Specification class, multiple Strongly-typed specifications are derived, which work well on their own. However, the problem arises when trying to combine such specifications and evaluating the CombinedSpecification in my Repository class:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet()
> .Where(c => c.ClientCode == __client_0 && c.Status == "Efective")' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

Here is a look at the CombinedSpecification class:

```
    internal class CombinedSpecification<T> : Specification<T>
    {
        private Specification<T> leftSpec;
        private Specification<T> rightSpec;

        public CombinedSpecification(Specification<T> aSpec, Specification<T> otherSpec)
        {
            this.leftSpec = aSpec;
            this.rightSpec = otherSpec;
        }

        public override Expression<Func<T, bool>> FilterExpr()
        {
            Expression<Func<T, bool>> firstExpr = this.leftSpec.FilterExpr();
            Expression<Func<T, bool>> secondExpr = this.rightSpec.FilterExpr();

            BinaryExpression combined = Expression.AndAlso(firstExpr.Body, secondExpr.Body);

            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(combined, firstExpr.Parameters.Single());
        }
    }
```

Just to be clear, filtering by a single specification works just fine, yet the LinQ expression seems impossible to translate when combining them (which seems weird to me since I'm not using any methods that are unsupported by SQL AFAIK). I avoided showing the Repository class to reduce this question's volume, but here is the relevant lines of my Find() method anyways:

```
    public IEnumerable<TEntity> Find(Specification<TEntity> spec)
        {
            IQueryable<TEntity> result = this.dbSet;

            if (spec != null)
            {
                result = result.Where(spec.FilterExpr());
            }

            return result.ToList();
        }
```

Thanks in advance for the help, I hope my first question was clearly stated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in your lambda expression combining implementation you use a body which combines the bodies of the two lambda expressions, but only the parameter of the first lambda expression (`firstExpr.Parameters.Single()`).

This way the second body still references a *different* parameter (even it visually might look the same, the parameters in lambda expressions are identifying by *reference*, not by name as you can think when creating them at compile time).

In other words, what you see in the error message

```cs
c => c.ClientCode == __client_0 && c.Status == "Efective"
```

is actually something like this

```cs
p0 => p0.ClientCode == __client_0 && p1.Status == "Efective"
```

which of course is invalid and cannot be translated (or compiled - try calling `Compile()` and you'll get runtime exception).

What you need is to make sure both operands as well as the resulting lambda expression use one and the same parameter instance.

You could still reuse the parameter of one of the operand, but you have to rebind the body of the other operand to the same parameter. Which usually is achieved with small custom `ExpressionVisitor` which finds all occurrences of a parameter inside the expression tree and replaces them with another parameter (or expression) - pretty much like `string.Replace`, but for expressions:

```cs
public static partial class ExpressionExtensions
{
    public static Expression ReplaceParameter(this Expression target, ParameterExpression parameter, Expression value)
        => new ParameterReplacer { Parameter = parameter, Value = value }.Visit(target);

    class ParameterReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        public ParameterExpression Parameter;
        public Expression Value;
        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
            => node == Parameter ? Value : node;
    }
}
```

and modify the combining implementation with something like this

```cs
public override Expression<Func<T, bool>> FilterExpr()
{
    var firstExpr = this.leftSpec.FilterExpr();
    var secondExpr = this.rightSpec.FilterExpr();

    var parameter = firstExpr.Parameters[0]; // <--
    var combined = Expression.AndAlso(
        firstExpr.Body, 
        secondExpr.Body.ReplaceParameter(secondExpr.Parameters[0], parameter) // <--
    );

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(combined, parameter); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely test this and bring an answer by tomorrow. However, would you mind going a bit more in depth about why the parameters are not the same? Shouldn't the CombinedSpecification be evaluating itself on the same entity?

What I'm trying to say is that I don't understand why the parameters of the first expression are not the same of the second one, if I'm not doing the filtering on memory but rather on the database side. Thanks in advance!

Comment: As I said, it won't work even in memory, because at the time you try to compile the expression to `Func` you'll get an error. And why are they not the same - because them come from two different compile time expressions - (A) `c => c.ClientCode == ...` and (B) `c => c .Status == ...`. You see? `c => ` in (A) is different from `c =>` in (B). I mentioned in the answer they are identified by reference, not by name. Would it be more clear if I wrote (A) `x => x.ClientCode == ...` and (B) `y => y.Status == ...`

Comment: Sorry, I know you mentioned it in the original answer, it's just that my lack of inexperience at working with the Expression type makes it hard for me to grasp. Thanks