# Cast IEnumerable into Array in Expression Tree Func

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, lambda, expression-trees, func

I have an expression that has the following structure. I get it from a [`Expression.ArrayIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352913.aspx), so I cannot change it:

```
Expression<Func<TModel[], TProperty>> expression
```

Afterwards I'm combining this expression with a parent one that has this structure:

```
Expression<Func<TDataSource, IEnumerable<TModel>>> dataSourceExpression
```

So the resultant expression should be:

```
Expression<Func<TDataSource, TProperty>>
```

Note that after combining them I use `TDataSource` as input and i get `TProperty` as result.
However I cannot combine them because `TModel[]` cannot be cast to `IEnumerable<TModel>`.

The combine is done like this:

```
Expression<Func<TDataSource, TProperty>> outputWithoutInline = dataSourceExpression.Combine(expression, true);

public static class ExpressionUtils
{
    public static Expression<Func<T1, T3>> Combine<T1, T2, T3>(
        this Expression<Func<T1, T2>> outer, Expression<Func<T2, T3>> inner, bool inline)
    {
        var invoke = Expression.Invoke(inner, outer.Body);
        Expression body = inline ? new ExpressionRewriter().AutoInline(invoke) : invoke;
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T1, T3>>(body, outer.Parameters);
    }
}
```

*More info about `ExpressionRewriter`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1720642/1587864

I want to keep using `IEnumerable`, and I really need an `Array` in the other expression. Is there any way I can do a casting of those expressions somehow, before merging them?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by combining them? Can you show more code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you had:

```
Expression<Func<TDataSource, IEnumerable<TModel>>> first = ...
Expression<Func<TModel[], TProperty>> second = ...
```

Why can't you just do:

```
Expression<Func<IEnumerable<TModel>, TModel[]>> converter = seq => seq.ToArray();

var result = first.Combine(converter, true).Combine(second, true);
```

You can try to be a little cuter with the converter if possible:

```
Expression<Func<IEnumerable<TModel>, TModel[]>> converter 
              = seq => (seq as TModel[]) ?? seq.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ's [`Enumerable.ToArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx) as an intermediate expression.

```
Expression<Func<IEnumerable<TModel>, TModel[]>> toArray = x => x.ToArray();
```

Comment: How can I execute this expression before combining?

Comment: @margabit Combine `dataSourceExpression` with `toArray`, and then combine the result of that with `expression`.